# shuffling a hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, shuffle

Is their anything better than this. I'm looking for a better shuffler and maybe a better way of coding this for making up for the lack of being able to shuffle a hash.

```
hdata.to_a.shuffle.to_h
```

Comment: What constitutes better? Since hash doesn't have a native shuffle method any solution is going to be a variation on what you already have. E.g. `hdata.slice(*hdata.keys.shuffle)`

Comment: yeah I suppose you are right.